# How can I quickly see which is the latest monthly cumulative update installed in a Windows PC?

Tags: windows, windows-update

Given a machine running Windows 10 or Windows 11, what is the quickest/easiest way to see the most recent cumulative update installed? I want to the know the Month/Year of the update, rather than the KB number.

I need to know what is actually installed, not what is available, and I don't know the KB numbers of any of the updates.

I'm not exactly looking for a script, but Powershell or batch options are allowed; I can't count on vbscript in this environment.

Comment: The quickest way is Windows Update history on the device then look up the update KB or simultaneously have the [Windows 10 Update History](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-10-update-history-8127c2c6-6edf-4fdf-8b9f-0f7be1ef3562) page open on a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Any Windows 10 or 11 operating system.

Start, Settings, Update, then Update History .

Everything you wish is list there. Main updates shown first, drivers and other updates lower down.

This is the fastest way to get the updates list. Just a handful of seconds.

Update details and dates shown.

[image: Windows Update History]